# How to make a dynamic execute of an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

There is an `AsyncTask` which will post data to a webserver. The number of parameters to put in the `execute` method is dynamic because it depends on the number of rows updated inside the SQLite database table. Here is how I call the execute method :

```
ArrayList<String> t_enregs = new ArrayList<String>();
t_enregs = db.getAllNewOrUpdatedParcelles(); // retrieving and formatting updated database rows
if (t_enregs.size() > 0) {
    tacheSend = new SendTask(SyncActivity.this);
    String parametres = "", sep = "";
    for (String enreg : t_enregs) {
        parametres += sep + enreg;
        sep = ",";
    }
    tacheSend.execute(parametres); // I want to make a dynamic call like execute("param1" , "param2")
}
```

I debugged it and it gives 1 as the dimension of the `params` parameter of the `doInBackground` method ! So how to make a dynamic call to the `execute` method in this case ?

Comment: Why not passing `t_enregs` as parameter to `execute` ?

Comment: Well your call is already 'dynamic' as you have one String parameter which contains a variable number of comma separated values.

Comment: @greenapps but the app recognize the parameters as one ! but not two for example

Comment: you can pass a `new String[]{ param1, param2, param3 }` as argument to `task.execute()`

Comment: `but the app recognize the parameters as one`. The app? I think it is YOUR doInBackground code? If you know that is is a csv String you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to make a dynamic call to the execute method in this case ?

Instead of preparing `Vargs Argument` using `for-loop` just pass `ArrayList<String> t_enregs` as parameter to `doInBackground` and use `params[0]` to get ArrayList for further processing:

```
tacheSend.execute(t_enregs);
```

In `doInBackground`  get ArrayList from `params`:

```
@Override
 protected StringBuilder doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params)
   {
      ArrayList<String> t_enregs=params[0];
      //...
  }
```